# Is there a way check for graphics only in the \graphicspath folder?

Tags: graphics, directory

I used the `\graphicspath` command to tell my LaTeX document where the various pictures are located. However, I noticed that LaTeX first checks the directory where the TeX file is located and only afterwards looks in the directory specified in `\graphicspath`.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to only look for graphics in the `\graphicspath` directory? Or is the only solution here to clean up the directory of the source file and make sure no graphics are located there?

Comment: I think latex will always check the folder with the tex file first and only then consult graphics path. (Perhaps it is also a good idea to use unique names for your graphics?)

Comment: you could change the internal macros to skip the current directory but simplest, if you want it to only look in a folder images is to use `\includegraphics{images/mypicture.png}`  with the path in the includegraphics argument

Answer (score 1):

A way where I suppose you have an image named `MyImage.png` inside a folder named `images`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\oldIncludegraphics\includegraphics

\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\oldIncludegraphics[#1]{images/#2}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{MyImage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So this overwrites the includegraphics command so that it attaches a directory to the file name?

Comment: I would go mad if some document would do this somewhere, and so e.g. \includegraphics{example-image} no longer works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right, but it is the only example I thought it will fail when thought about it... Just an idea for this specific need. quarague.. Yes, this is exactly how it works.